# Getting file size by id in jquery

Tags: jquery, file

How do I get the size of a file by its id and not by this method `(this.files[0].size)`. I need something like this `$("#file").size();` or `document.getElementById('file').size();`.
Please any idea?

Comment: You can try `$("#file")[0].files[0].size` (untested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
     alert( $('#file')[0].files[0].size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="file" type="file"/>
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="Test"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If this answer helpful to you, mark it as useful.